Sitefinity sending email in controller
Within sitefinity-cms is there a way I can send email in an mvc controller?  I see alot about  Email campaigns settings but nothing related to sending email in code?

Not an answer, but it needs to be way way way easier to send, the API needs some hardcore developer love, but we just never get it.
Should be like
xmanager.SendEmail(to, from, subject, body) maybe pick the notification sender or something... it's obnoxiously complex.  I usually just roll my own sender helper and use the Config API to reference the SMTP settings.
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-notification-service
